# How to Parse an incoming JSON response from an API and update the MySql database using PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, api

I am working on the backend panel of an e-commerce site and we are required to send order details to our Delivery vendor's REST API so that details get updated on their own dashboard and they schedule a pickup from our warehouse automatically. I have sent a JSON formatted request having the package details to which I have received a JSON success response back from the API.

Now I am facing an issue.

How can i parse this response and update my MySQL database according to it?
The JSON response gets displayed on the website and It's just plain text. It's all on the frontend and goes away when i refresh the page.

Since I have no knowledge of what is the name of the POST parameter the response has, I cannot "catch" the json by PHP (  $_POST['...'] ) and manipulate it's content by using regular expressions.

I have to parse the contents of the response and update the package's "tracking_number" if API's response is "success", in MYSql database.

How to go about it?
Am I being clear with my query?

HERE ARE THE IMAGES : 
[The JSON being displayed right on the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOISi.jpg)

Comment: You could always [`var_dump($_POST);`](http://php.net/var_dump) to see what it contains, then use [`json_decode();`](http://php.net/json_decode) on the appropriate `$_POST` property.

Comment: I tried using these but it is not receiving the json stream at all. Instead it is waiting indefinitely.